# How can I retrieve the Strong Key of a assembly

Tags: c#, assemblies, strongname

How do I retrieve the Strong Key of an assembly using C#? Is there a method that will work for .Net and non-.Net assemblies. I've just received a request to uniquely identify assemblies across a number of systems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to retrieve the public key token of the signed assembly, check the following [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/07/01/how-to-find-public-key-token-for-a-net-dll-or-assembly.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
var key = assembly.GetName().GetPublicKey();
var keyToken = assembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken();
```

If you need as string try this

```
var keyTokenString = string.Join("", assembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken().Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
```

Comment: OK, so that looks a lot simpler than I was expecting. Not sure why I got no results when I Googled "c# get assembly strong key". Now that should uniquely identify my .Net assemblies, what about non-.Net ones? What's the best method for identifying them?

Comment: Hmmm sorry, am not sure about that